# Continuous colourmap in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a 3D graph with `matplotlib` using the `plot_surface` command, but the colour scheme looks discrete on the plot. Is there a way to have a continuous colour gradient between the points?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(2, figsize=(8,6))
plt.rcParams.update({"font.size":16})

ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('$t$', labelpad=10)
ax.set_ylabel('$x$', labelpad=10)
ax.set_zlabel('$Y(x,t)$', labelpad=10)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(6))
ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(6))

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0))

ax.plot_surface(t, x, Yplot, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.viridis)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here is an example of what I mean by "discrete colour scheme":

[image: Plot]

Comment: What are you expecting to see? Can you show us what is "continuous  colour gradient"?

Comment: Something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xlVE.png, you can see here that there is a colour gradient in an element, unlike my plot where the colour is solid in each element.

Comment: Can you add a way to generate t,x and YPlot so that this is an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). basically, I should be able to copy your code into a fresh python environment and it should result in that plot showing up.